# Как в LINQ запросе сравнивать ValueObjects?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

У меня есть абстрактный класс ValueObject и наследующий его Account.
В Account есть 2 свойства, и я сделал возможность сравнивать их по этим двум свойствам.
Этот Account хранится в базе данных как не обьект, а как два этих свойства. Во время одной работы с базой данных, я пытался найти, существует ли данная запись с таким Account. Но я получаю исключение

`System.InvalidOperationException: No backing field could be found for property 'Account.BotMemberId' and the property does not have a getter.`

Зайдя в снапшот модели миграций, я увидел левое свойство

```cs
b1.Property<Guid>("BotMemberId")
    .HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier");
```

Его здесь не должно быть, так как мешает в работе с базой данных.

Конфигурация сущности:

```cs
builder.ToTable("Members");
builder.HasKey(m => m.Id);

builder
    .Property<string>(m => m.FirstName)
    .HasColumnName("First name")
    .IsRequired();

builder
    .Property(m => m.Level)
    .HasColumnName("Current Level")
    .HasDefaultValue(0);

builder
    .Property(m => m.Experience)
    .HasColumnName("Current experience")
    .HasDefaultValue(0);

builder.OwnsOne(m => m.Account, a =>
{
    a.Property(account => account.TelegramId)
        .HasColumnName("TelegramId")
        .IsRequired();
    a.Property(account => account.ChatId)
        .HasColumnName("ChatId")
        .IsRequired();
});
```

Сущность:

```cs
// невозможно создать Account для EF при добавлении миграции,
// поэтому я сделал приватный конструктор, который его не принимает
private BotMember()
{
    
}
public BotMember(Guid id, string firstName, Account account)
{
    Id = id;
    FirstName = firstName;
    Account = account;
    Level = 0;
    Experience = 0f;
}

public Guid Id { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public Account Account { get; set; }
public int Level { get; set; }
public float Experience { get; set; }
```

ValueObject:

```cs
public class Account : ValueObject, IEquatable<Account>
{
    public Account(long telegramId, long chatId)
    {
        TelegramId = telegramId;
        ChatId = chatId;
    }

    public long TelegramId { get; set; }
    public long ChatId { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Account? other)
    {
        return base.Equals(other);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetEqualityComponents()
    {
        yield return TelegramId;
        yield return ChatId;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Account left, Account right)
    {
        return left.Equals(right);
    }
    public static bool operator !=(Account left, Account right)
    {
        return !left.Equals(right);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{TelegramId}:{ChatId}";
    }
}
```

Сам код, по которому я понял что руки у меня не прямые

```cs
return await _db.Members
    .AnyAsync(dbMember => dbMember.Account == targetMember.Account, cancellationToken);
// System.InvalidOperationException: No backing field could be found for property 'Account.BotMemberId' and the property does not have a getter
```

Comment: `Account` хранится в той же таблице `members`. Свойство `"BotMemberId"` никакое не левое, оно является необходимо для работы навигации между сущностями. Как и чем оно мешает?

Comment: Тут явно сказывается [Object–relational impedance mismatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object%E2%80%93relational_impedance_mismatch) - несоответствие реляционной и объектной модели. В БД обе сущности хранятся в одной таблице. А в коде C# наличествуют две сущности; между ними нужно как-то реализовать связь. Вот это внутреннее свойство и необходимо для этой связи.

Comment: Вы не показали главное: код, который выкидывает исключение. / Вы понимаете, что операторы `==`, `!=` не транслируются в sql? Они существуют только в клиентском коде c#.

Comment: [Implement value objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/implement-value-objects).  [Value Comparers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-comparers?tabs=ef5)

Comment: Здравствуйте, Александр! Извиняюсь, что так поздно отвечаю, ибо не было возможности выйти в сеть.

Comment: У меня в базе хранится только сущность `BotMember`. ValueObject `Account` я добавил, чтобы делать выборку определённой записи намного легче. Сам по себе, `Account` не хранится в базе данных. (По крайней мере я так думаю, потому что не добавлял его. Если я чего-то не знал, то извиняюсь за это, и хотел бы пояснения)

Comment: `No backing field could be found for property 'Account.BotMemberId' and the property does not have a getter.`, как раз мне это и мешает. Я думаю, что он хочет обратиться к моему полю `BotMemberId`, которого в ValueObject классе не существует. Если смотреть туториал от майкрософтцев и метанита, то они не добавляли такого "навигационного поля". Пытался повторить код уже под свои нужды, но не сильно и получилось, раз мне вылезает эта ошибка

Comment: `А в коде C# наличествуют две сущности; между ними нужно как-то реализовать связь.`
Я думал, что если я в сущности буду хранить обьект типа ValueObject, то EntityFramework возьмет из этого ValueObject все публичные свойства, и засунет в сущность для его сохранения в базу данных

Comment: `Вы понимаете, что операторы ==, != не транслируются в sql? Они существуют только в клиентском коде c#.`
Правда говоря, я думал что транслируются. Выходит мне надо заполнять пробелы в знаниях...